# Excel warning opening file created with xlwt: file error

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm trying to write a .xls file using xlwt on windows, Python 2.7, xlwt 7.4.  I'm using Excel 2013.

I made an easyxf format:

```
borders =  "borders: top thin, bottom thin, left thin, right thin;"
align   =  "align: wrap on, vert centre, horiz centre;"
pattern =  'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour ' + color_f(center) + ";"
pct     =  "num_format_str = 0%"
pct_style = xlwt.easyxf(pattern + borders + align, pct )
```

and wrote these cells:

```
ws.write (xlrow, 7, 1.0 * optempo / span, pct_style)
ws.write (xlrow, 8, 1.0 - total / n_workdays, pct_style)
```

When I open the .xls, a pop-up says "File error: some number formats may have been lost."  The cells are formatted as integers or reals, and not as percents.  There are no other problems.  The values are mathematically correct.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are including the parameter name `num_format_str` in your `pct` string, which is wrong.

Try:

```
borders =  "borders: top thin, bottom thin, left thin, right thin;"
align   =  "align: wrap on, vert centre, horiz centre;"
pattern =  'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour ' + color_f(center) + ";"
pct     =  "0%"
pct_style = xlwt.easyxf(pattern + borders + align, num_format_str = pct)
```

[See here](http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Style.easyxf) for further info on `xlwt.easyxf()`